# CSOM vs REST in sharepoint 2013 in terms of performance

Tags: rest, client-object-model

CSOM vs REST in sharepoint 2013 in terms of performance and why.I have been having this question for a long time and I have not got a clear picture on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you checkout this blog post and the associated presentation. In both of these resources, David Mann details his findings around performance differences.

[SPC423 Recap: Deep Dive – REST and CSOM Comparison](http://blog.mannsoftware.com/?p=1521)

[Deep dive: REST and CSOM comparison](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC423)